# What do these networkx errors mean which I am getting after setting a filter on my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, compiler-errors, networkx

I have a source, target and weight dataframe called `Gr_Team` which looks like this (sample) -

```
Passer Receiver  count
116643   102747     27
102826   169102     10
116643   102826      7
167449   102826      8
102747   167449      4
```

Each Passer and Receiver have their unique x,y co-ordinates which I have in a dictionary `loc` - `{'102739': [32.733999999999995, 26.534], '102747': [81.25847826086964, 27.686739130434784], '102826': [68.09609195402302, 77.52206896551728]}`
I plotted this using networkx:

```
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(Gr_Team, 'Passer', 'Receiver', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

nx.draw(G, loc, with_labels=False, node_color='red',
            node_size=Gr_Team['count']*100,
            width=Gr_Team['count'],
            edge_color = Gr_Team["count"],
            edge_cmap = cmap,
            arrowstyle='->',
            arrowsize=10,
            vmin=vmin,
            vmax=vmax,
            font_size=10,
            font_weight="bold",
            connectionstyle='arc3, rad=0.1')
```

That worked without any issues and here's what I got:
[image]

However, as soon as I try to filter out all the rows with count value below a constant, let's say 3, using this `Gr_Team = Gr_Team[Gr_Team["count"]>3]`, I get a key error and here's the entire error and traceback which I can't make anything out of:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 676
    if cb.iterable(node_size):  # many node sizes
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The iterable function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use np.iterable instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\PassMapOptaF24Networkx.py", line 148, in <module>
    font_weight="bold")#,
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 128, in draw
    draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 280, in draw_networkx
    edge_collection = draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=arrows, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 684, in draw_networkx_edges
    arrow_color = edge_cmap(color_normal(edge_color[i]))
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 868, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4375, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 81, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 89, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 987, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 993, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1
```

I realized that doing only `nx.draw(G, loc, with_labels=False, node_color='red')` still worked but as soon as I try to pass `node_size` or `edge_color`, it hits the above error. From my understanding, the error is only when I'm using the dataframe `Gr_Team` in the keyword arguments.

I can't figure out why that's happening and why filtering breaks the code. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**: [Here](https://gist.github.com/AbhishekSharma99/446116421e8e97fe2dcacb8a0f96a38c)'s a gist of the entire code. I tried my best to keep it minimal. [Here](https://github.com/AbhishekSharma99/Opta-Data-Feed/blob/master/PSGCopy_NancyLyonAllEvents.csv)'s the link to the csv file that needs to be read in as df. The line which produces the error is in also in there; commented out.

Comment: Can you give the exact function call that is yielding your error?  From what I'm seeing, the fact you've got a KeyError suggests that it's looking for something in `Gr_Team` which has been filtered out.

Comment: The exact function is just this: `Gr_Team = Gr_Team[Gr_Team["count"]>3]`

Comment: Is that the function that gets the error?  Or is it a drawing command?

Comment: I guess, can you give a [MCVE] that produces this error?

Comment: I updated the gist in the question @Joel
Yes, the drawing command gets the error but it works fine until the fiter to dataframe is applied so I'm not sure where the error arises from

Comment: Without fully understanding what's going on, I suggest you look at `G.nodes`, and look at `Gr_Team['count']` (is it just a number, or something list-like?).  I think `Gr_Team['count']` is list-like, and I suspect it is not as long as `list(G.nodes())` because some of the things you've filtered out will still make it into the nodes if they show up in any edges.  (I also suspect it's unlikely to be in the same order).

Comment: Yeah, I could plot the nodes and edges individually, creating a function. However, that doesn't solve this specific problem and I was looking forward to using networkx's pandas functionality instead of plotting every row separately. 
No, `Gr_Team["count"]` is  a single scalar quantity for every row - it's just the weight of the link between the two nodes. It's not list-like; I just checked. 
If the order is not being conserved, that's truly a problem. 
What do you mean by this - " because some of the things you've filtered out will still make it into the nodes if they show up in any edges"?

Comment: Just figured out that changing `nx.DiGraph` to `nx.Graph` removes the errors but I lose all the attributes. Maybe the problem was with the wrong type of graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These error lines give a good hint:

> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> KeyError: 1

The problem seems to be that passing the `Gr_Team` - dataframe to specifiy `node_size`, `width` and `edge_color` requires the indices to be consecutive. Using

```
Gr_Team = Gr_Team[Gr_Team["count"] > 3 ].reset_index()
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Great, that did solve the problem! However, as mentioned by @Joel, the consistency of the node list is not being preserved. Is there something in the code to ensure that that doesn't happen?